# How to copy multiple links of dropbox

Tags: kml, dropbox, google-fusion-tables, dropbox-api

I have a folder on my dropbox account, that have other 400 folders with files inside.
I need to share these folders links, because I want to link a polygon feature from a kml to these links.
So, I have a KML, with 400 polygons. I've uploaded this KML to a Fusiontables, so I can apply automaticaly style to them.
Every polygon has one folder into my dropbox account, and I want to link them.
What I have to do, is copy every "shared link" of my dropbox (400 shared links) and fill a column named DROPBOX on my fusiontables containing my 400 polygons KML.

It's too painfully to do that kind of thing, it takes about 4 steps to copy one single folder link. I have 400 folders, 400 x 4 = 1600 steps...

I've tried Dropbox Chooser API to display Multiple links. But I've got only links of files, not folder's links.

Does anyone experienced on Dropbox or with a great mind, can help me out?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dropbox API for share any files or folders in Dropbox account:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#shares

Then save all stored data in CSV file and import in Fusiontables.

Answer (score 0):

Super simple [solution](https://primesellerhub.com/2018/03/15/make-dropbox-image-links-bulk/) by dragging all the images from the shared folder and pressing CTRL + C to copy all links. Then you can paste all the links.

**Note: Make sure you are logged out of your dropbox account as it says in the post**

Comment: I have seen this link you mention in different posts as I search for an answer but it says it is a private site and requires me to log in.  Is this method explained anywhere else?